# i am using spring mvc with tiles 3 but after deployment jsp page is not coming it is displayed as html code

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

```
    <%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%> 
    <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%> 
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %> 

<!DOCTYPE html > 
<html> <head> 
<title> 
<%-- <tiles:getAsString name="title"/> --%> 
</title> 
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../wro/main.css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="../wro/main.js"></script> --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/catalyststyle.css" media="screen"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/calendar.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/chosen/chosen.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/overrides.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="../js/calendar_us.js">
</script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jqueryui/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.simplemodal.min.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<table class="tblone" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr> 
<td class="header"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/></td> 
</tr> </table> <table class="greenbg" cellspacing="2"> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top"><fmt:message key="msg.cis"/></td> 
<%-- <c:if test="${!empty user}"> 
<td valign="top" align="right"> 
<fmt:message key="sso.logged"/> 
<c:out value = "${user.name}"/> 
</td> </c:if> --%> </tr> </table> <table class="tblone" cellspacing="2"> <tr> 
<td valign="top" class="hdrText">
<tiles:insertAttribute name="modules"/></td> 
<td>&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<table class="tblone" cellspacing="2"> 
<tr> <td valign="top" class="tblthree"><%-- <tiles:getAsString name="title"/> --%></td> 
<td>&nbsp;</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<table class="tblone" cellspacing="2"> 
<tr> 
<td valign="top" class="tablnav"><tiles:insertAttribute name="navigation"/></td> 
<td valign="top" class="tbltwo">
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<table class="tblone" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr/> 
<tr/> 
<tr/>
<tr/> 
<tr> 
<td><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/></td> 
</tr>
</table> 
</body> 
</html>
```

---

Comment: what does your configuration look like, your jsp, whats being returned to you?  You need to provide more detail to get your question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your replay, i solved the problem, problem is,  in the top line of the jsp i have given the jsp page directive  ie..
"<%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%> "

this is not loading, so i configured my web.xml with CharacterEncodingFilter so problem solved